# Django modelcluster: When/How to invalidate cached_properties?

Tags: python, django

In a project of mine, I ran into an issue with a `cached_property`.

Following is a minimal example reproducing this:

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel


class Author(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @cached_property
    def fictional_books(self):
        return self.books.filter(fictional=True)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = ParentalKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books')
    fictional = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
>>> from app.models import *
>>> a = Author.objects.create(name='John Smith')
>>> print(', '.join([ str(book) for book in a.fictional_books ]))

>>> a.books.add(Book(title='My Fun Story', fictional=True))
>>> a.books.add(Book(title='My Real Story', fictional=False))
>>> print(', '.join(a.fictional_books))

>>> del a.fictional_books
>>> print(', '.join([ str(book) for book in a.fictional_books ]))
My Fun Story
```

What can be seen here is the cached property `fictional_books` retaining its old value of an empty query set, because it was first accessed when there were no fictional books associated with that author.

However, after adding books to that author, this is obviously not correct anymore, and once the cached result is deleted, we get the correct result.

One obvious solution to this would be to avoid `cached_property` completely and to use `property` instead.

However, as the access to that property might hit the database, it seems like it is a good idea to use a `cached_property`.

I am wondering now, what is the best common practice to work with `cached_properties` in this situation?

Should it be the responsibility of the user of the model instance to clear cached properties when they make changes?

This seems a bit weird as I would presume usage of `cached_property` vs `property` to be an implementation detail that the user of the model should not need to care about.

Should it be the responsibility of the model instance to clear its cached properties when
changes to it are being made that invalidate those properties?

This seems like a better approach from the perspective of the users of the model, however I am not sure how this could be implemented.

Comment: One hack is you can raise an error for "empty" results. The proper way to do this is to use a custom decorator that caches results in something like redis. Then again I'm not sure what your specifications are for caching something (how long should it stay valid etc)

Comment: The `cached_property` is not relating to an external cache, but to a cache that is associated with an instance of the model.

It is stored in the instance's `__dict__` dictionary.

It is perfectly valid for the property to return an empty value if there are no results, so it is not really an option to raise an error in that case.